# Changing colorbar numbers

Tags: matlab, figure, colorbar

I have a dataset which has a scatter3 plot with a matrix for colourspace ranging between -2.5 and 0. The blue part of the colourspace is associated with the values that are lower therefore the -2.5. This is OK.

I would like to be able to edit the colorbar so that I can change which value is associated with the ends of the colourbar manually. So that only on the figure I can set -2.5 to be 0 and 0 to be 2.5. The changes need to be cosmetic only.

Is there a way of doing this using the caxis command?

Thanks!

Comment: Everything can be done in this case. But if you want an answer, give us some code to play with.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example in the same kind,

```
set cbtics ("-2.5" -2.5, "-1.5" -1.5, "0" 0, "1.5" 1.5, "2.5" 2.5)
set palette defined (-2.5 "color1", -1.5 "color1", -1.5 "color2", 0 "color2", 0 "color3", ...)
plot your data
```

Note:- each color will repeat twice one for starting and another for ending.